# How to add remote server on phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using phpstorm for the first time.Now , I want to create a project from my exsiting project which is written under sublime before . After I chose create project from exsting folders, phpstorm tells me to add remote server.But,this project is only a local project until now,why and how should I add remote server?How can I skip this step?

Comment: Most likely you have selected the wrong option. My suggestion: forget about "Create new project" wizard -- just use "Open" and point to your project root folder -- everything else can be configured later manually if required.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Thanks！I   have started my first project on phpstorm!